# how to remove glyphs from vtk data?

Tags: c++, vtk

I am wondering if there is a vtk filter that replaces glyps (cone source) with a single vertex?

Here is the problem i am trying to solve.  I have bunch of vector field data displayed using cone glyps. I am trying to pick a vector glyph and display vector values.  I am using vtkCellPicker to pick the vector glyph.  The cell picker is picking the face on the glyph instead of picking the whole glyph.  So, the vector values picked are values on the face, not for the entire glyph.

If i can run the vtkData through some filter which replaces these glyps with a single vertex, i can pick the point and pick the correct vector field values.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `vtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter` (http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter.html#details) to pull out the whole glyph starting from the one cell that is picked.

You may be better off setting `GeneratePointIdsOn` on your `vtkGlyph3D` filter which will add to the cone data an extra array with input point IDs. You can then use this to look up the original data value for display. See http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkGlyph3D.html#a1d7bfd7779ca2e229423a33a2e36e741